# Setting up linux build agent for teamcity

Tags: linux, teamcity, agent

I am trying to install a build agent on linux for teamcity.  I downloaded the buildAgent.zip file and extracted it.  I renamed the buildAgent.dist.properties file to buildAgent.properties as instructed by the teamcity documentation.  I edited the file with the server url and the port number i will be using(ex: 150).  On the teamcity server machine i opened port 150.  I opened a command shell and executed the ./agent.sh start command and it says it started but it is not showing up in the list on the teamcity server.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are you really using port 150?  Are you running the TC server as root?

Comment: TC Server is installed on a windows server and the agent is on a different machine.  TC Server is on port 100 and the agent im trying to run will use port 150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port numbers below 1024 can be accessed only by the root user on Linux. Just use the default ports and everything should work fine.

[Agent and Server logs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Logs+of+Internal+Events) should help you to identify the problem.

Comment: I tired using the default but it still doesn't show up.  The logs say it connected to the server.  Still doesn't show up in the list though.

Comment: Did you authorize the agent? See http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/Agents#Agents-Unauthorizedagents

Comment: Please send the most recent logs from both server and the agent to support@jetbrains.com